# PHP's strlen is not the same as C's strlen, is it?

Tags: php, strlen

I'm trying to understand something. In C, [strlen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) method does the following -- it scans a given string of characters and counts them up until it gets to a NULL, or 0 ASCII character.

[strlen](http://php.net/strlen) in PHP doesn't do the same, does it?

For instance, if I do this:

```
$s = "abc\0def";
$ln = strlen($s);
```

In C, `ln` would be returned as 3, but in PHP it would be 7. How does PHP's strlen count them? It obviously doesn't use NULL terminators.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? PHP doesn't stop at a NULL or 0 ASCII character. Every character in a string gets counted.

Comment: PHP uses Pascal strings. The zval union stores a `char*` and an `int` for the length.

Comment: The given example says your question answer.

Comment: @mario: Thank you. You should post it as an answer and I will mark it. As I noted in my comment to Hugo's post, I need to know how "fast" PHP's `strlen` is. So if it stores the length internally, it should be really fast (unlike C's `strlen`.)

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly as the [documentation](http://php.net/strlen) says it is.

```
Note:

strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.
```

Comment: The documentation also says this up front, `"Returns the length of the given string."` Now I see that I have to scroll down almost a page to see the note you quoted, which, in my book, is not exactly the same.

Comment: So, the reason I'm asking, is to ascertain how "fast" PHP's `strlen` is. For instance, if we're talking about a 1GB long string, calling C's `strlen` would be quite a slow proposition. If I'm understanding correctly, PHP's `strlen` will not scan through the whole string to know its length, and will work really fast, right?

Comment: I used it long ago in an attempt to bypass insufficient memory with var_dump. It almost doesnt even use memory to calculate, so yeah it is fast. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13929975/434949

Comment: Ps> if you ever use php docs, remember to read everything including examples, notes and (top) comments. They often provide nore insight then the actual info.

Answer (score 2):

PHP stores strings internally as a list of bytes, and the length as integer. Every value in PHP is represented as a ["zval"](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php):

```
typedef union _zvalue_value {
    long lval;                 /* long value */
    double dval;               /* double value */
    struct {                   
        char *val;
        int len;               /* this will always be set for strings */
    } str;                     /* string (always has length) */
    HashTable *ht;             /* an array */
    zend_object_value obj;     /* stores an object store handle, and handlers */
} zvalue_value;
```

So they're basically like strings in Pascal (`int` and `char*`), so there's no need to look for a NUL byte. [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) therefore just returns the already-known length without further string traversal.

The [`ZEND_FUNCTION(strlen)` implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L502) just returns `s->len`. It obviously has to turn that string length into another `zval`, so that this integer can be consumed within PHP again.

Comment: I gues the `strpos` part should be `strlen`?

Comment: Yes, @mario, did you mean `strlen`?

Comment: @c00000fd Em, yes, the answer is about strlen.

Comment: @mario: Can you then change it (your main post above) and I'll mark it.