# ob_start() doesn't work on large outputs

Tags: php

I'm wondering if this is a PHP.ini config issue.  I find that, with large data sets, I can't echo incremented values.

```
<?php

ob_start();
*SQL query*
$count++;

$search_results = ob_get_clean();
echo $count;
echo $search_results;


?>
```

The code itself works, but with large data sets it doesn't appear at all.  I'm wondering if this is a cacheing issue?

Comment: Have you tested with `ob_get_length()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use var\_dump + output buffering without memory errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446647/how-can-i-use-var-dump-output-buffering-without-memory-errors). Title isn't the same, but the objective is.

Comment: What is your php memory_limit, and how large is the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a memory issue, it was related to php.ini settings.  In particular, the max_execute time was not high enough.  I changed it to;

```
max_execution_time = 600
```

Solved the issue.

Comment: Interesting. If it's the database lagging on a query, you may want to try to optimize some of your queries using database indexes. Increasing the max execution time will only get you so far since it doesn't solve the underlying problem (the problem being the code is slow).

Comment: The script is a bit involved and there are multiple queries per device (1000 devices) that get pulled - unavoidable given the nature of the query.  Also, I don't have access to the database, it's a locked appliance.